# Docker mount doesn't seem to be doing anything

Tags: linux, docker

I don't think I understand the purpose of mounts/volumes in docker. On the (debian) host machine, I am:

```
mkdir testdir
touch testdir/testfile
nano Dockerfile
```

And adding:

```
FROM debian:11
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=./testdir,target=/testdir
RUN ls /testdir
```

Then running `docker build .`

I would expect the `ls` command to print out `testfile`. But it seems as though nothing was actually mounted? (Note the mount command ran just fine).

```
--------------------
  1 |     FROM debian:11
  2 |     RUN --mount=type=bind,source=./testdir,target=/testdir
  3 | >>> RUN ls /testdir
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c ls /testdir" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2
```

What am I missing here? What is the point of `target` if it doesn't even create a directory to its target?

(Running docker 24.0.5, and buildx 0.11.2)

Comment: You can't control volumes from within the `Dockerfile`. You have to specify them when you `docker run` the image. Anything else would be a serious security issue.

Comment: @tripleee This would be a [build-time mount](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run---mount), not runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you've missed one improtant detail: you're running `ls /testdir` in a separate `RUN` instruction. I'm not sure, but I guess it's only possible with `--mount=type=cache`.

You're using `bind` so your mount persists only within the same `RUN` intsruction.

Try something like this:

```
FROM debian:11
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=./testdir,target=/testdir \
  ls /testdir
```

**EDIT:**

I just tested both versions and they're both working just fine on my machines.

The problem must be with docker itself or additional tools you're using, like buildkit or buildx

Comment: Although its weird you cannot reproduce the problem, your instruction to execute everything on one RUN did work.